# `DateListPlot`: not a valid dataset or list of datasets?

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.2 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.1**

---

Simple Code:

```
DateListPlot[<|
  "A44" -> {{{1992, 12, 1}, 1}, {{1992, 12, 2}, 2}, {{1992, 12, 3}, 
     3}}, "A45" -> {{{1992, 12, 1}, 4}, {{1992, 12, 2}, 
     5}, {{1992, 12, 3}, 6}}|>]
```

But Mathematica tells me it is not a valid dataset or list of datasets.

However, if I change "A44" and "A45" to "A4" and "A5", the plot is correct.

Any fixes?

Comment: It appears as if the key is of the form "a__dd__" DateListPlot will fail.  i.e. any alpha sequence followed by at least two digits.

Comment: This has been reported as a bug.

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed on 11.0.1.

```
DateListPlot[<|
 "A44" -> {{{1992, 12, 1}, 1}, {{1992, 12, 2}, 2}, {{1992, 12, 3}, 3}}, 
 "A45" -> {{{1992, 12, 1}, 4}, {{1992, 12, 2}, 5}, {{1992, 12, 3}, 6}}|>]
```

[image]

Comment: I still have the same error: `DateListPlot::ldata: <|Bhutan->Missing[KeyAbsent,Bhutan],Kiribati->Missing[KeyAbsent,Kiribati],Vanuatu->Missing[KeyAbsent,Vanuatu]|> is not a valid dataset or list of datasets`, although I have MMA version 11.3. Dataset is read correctly as I see it and dataset has no problem at all. Can you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: @TugrulTemel I think the issue is you have `Missing` data. You'll have to prune those data sets.

Comment: Should I get rid of `Missing[]` elements in the dataset?

Comment: @TugrulTemel to plot it, yes.